# How to access value based on index from array defined in state ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on reactjs.my state looks like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      open: []
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    let {open} = this.state;
    for(var  i=0;i<nextProps.groupB.length;i++){
      open[i]=false;
    }

    this.setState({open:open})
}
```

Now I want access this values by index so I tried like this:

```
<div className="panel-body">
              {this.props.groupB.map((data,index) =>
                <div className="panel panel-default">
  <Button
      onClick={() =>
          this.setState({
             open: !this.state.open[index]
           })}
       >
       <Glyphicon
           glyph={
           this.state.open[index]
           ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus'
            : 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus'
       }
     />
  </Button>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<Collapse in={this.state.open}>
<Well>//...some code
</Well>
</Collapse>
</div>
```

I may have searched wrong in google. but not getting proper soln

Comment: just a note, you should avoid mutating state if at all possible thus you should use `let open = [...this.state.open];` as opposed to `let { open } = this.state;`

Answer (score 0):

make a click handler like this

```
clickHandler(e, index) {
   let open = [...this.state.open];
   open[index] = !open[index];
   this.setState({ open });
}
```

and then call that click handler like so...

```
onClick={e => this.clickHandler(e, index)}
```

Comment: what modification should I do in my Glyphicon class?

Comment: I think it is okay as is, one thing, why not map through `this.state.open` ?

Comment: my whole panel became invisible :(...wait will add some more code so it makes sense to you..UPDATED

Comment: because above map giving values to that

Comment: You're accessing your click handler by calling `this.clickHandler(...)` in your anonymous function; you don't need to bind it to `this`.

Comment: Very true @philraj, I do it out of habit, will remove from answer

Comment: Well it's not a bad habit, I just wanted to point out that it's not absolutely necessary in this case. :-)

Comment: bdw by whole box is just invisible now..:(